# The method getTeamName() is undefined for the type ArrayList<Team> - Error code, Java

Tags: java, android, arraylist

I'm trying to create a simple android app and I've come across a problem which i'm not sure how to fix.
I'm new to Android and Java so if you can help, it would be much appreciated.

Here is my code:

```
public class arraylist extends ListActivity {

ArrayList<Team> teams = new ArrayList<Team>();

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //Creating the array list
    teams.add(new Team("Everton ", "everton", "Liverpool", "1878", "Jagielka", "Premier League"));
    teams.add(new Team("Arsenal ", "arsenal", "London", "1886", "Arteta", "Premier League"));
    teams.add(new Team("Manchester United ", "manutd", "Manchester", "1878", "Rooney", "Premier League"));
    teams.add(new Team("Leeds United ", "leedsutd", "Leeds", "1919", "Cooper", "Championship"));
    CustomAdapter custAdapter = new CustomAdapter(this, teams);
    setListAdapter(custAdapter);
    registerForContextMenu(getListView());
}

protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
    Team t = teams.get(position);
    Toast.makeText(this, t.getTeamName() + "are a team from " + t.getLocation() + ".", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}


public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenuInfo main) {
    super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, main);
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
}



public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();
    String itemTitle = (String) item.getTitle();
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.year:
        Toast.makeText(this, teams.getTeamName() + " were created in " + teams.getYear() + ".", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return true;
    case R.id.captain:
        Toast.makeText(this, teams.getCaptain() + " is the current captain of " + teams.getTeamName() + ".", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return true;
    case R.id.league:
        Toast.makeText(this, teams.getTeamName() + "are currently in the " + teams.getLeague() + ".", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return true;
    }
    return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
}
}
```

And here is my Team.java:

```
public class Team {
private String teamName;
private String imageName;
private String location;
private String year;
private String captain;
private String league;

Team (String teamName, String imageName, String location, String year, String captain, String league) {
    this.teamName = teamName;
    this.imageName = imageName;
    this.location = location;
    this.year = year;
    this.captain = captain;
    this.league = league;
}

public void setTeamName(String teamName) {
    this.teamName = teamName;
}
public void setImageName(String imageName) {
    this.imageName = imageName;
}
public void setLocation(String location) {
    this.location = location;
}
public void setYear(String year) {
    this.year = year;
}
public void setCaptain(String captain) {
    this.captain = captain;
}
public void setLeague(String league) {
    this.league = league;
}

public String getTeamName() {
    return teamName;
}
public String getImageName() {
    return imageName;
}
public String getLocation() {
    return location;
}
public String getYear() {
    return year;
}
public String getCaptain() {
    return captain;
}
public String getLeague() {
    return league;
}

}
```

I'm getting an error here saying "The method getTeamName() is undefined for the type ArrayList" I also get this for the other time I try to call from the ArrayList:

```
    Toast.makeText(this, teams.getTeamName() + " were created in " + teams.getYear() + ".", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return true;
    case R.id.captain:
        Toast.makeText(this, teams.getCaptain() + " is the current captain of " + teams.getTeamName() + ".", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return true;
    case R.id.league:
        Toast.makeText(this, teams.getTeamName() + "are currently in the " + teams.getLeague() + ".", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return true;
```

Any tips or help?
I'm sorry if this is a simple fix, I've not been doing Java for long.

Thanks,
Dom

Comment: Erm... why have you called your class 'arraylist'?

Comment: @condorcraft110II While a strange choice for a class name, it's not related to the problem.

Comment: @Eran Indeed, but it's a good idea to instil good naming practice in the OP, especially if they're new to Java. OP, Java class names conventionally use PascalCase - i.e. the first letter of every word is capitalised. Also, pick a more descriptive name - 'ArrayList' is a standard API class.

Comment: @condorcraft110II I called it that because I didn't really know what else to call it. I didn't realise that the name was anything more than recognising it from other classes and since I only have 2 other classes in my project I didn't think it important. Thanks for the tip though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is wrong :

```
teams.getTeamName()
```

`getTeamName()` is a method of `Team`, not of `ArrayList<Team>`.

It should be

```
teams.get(i).getTeamName()
```

for some `i` between `0` and `teams.size()-1`.

The same goes for `teams.getCaptain()`, `teams.getLeague()`, etc...

Comment: I have 4 things in my list, it should output a different output (e.g. a different team name) for each of them in the list, but I just tried this and it outputted the same team name and year for all of them.

I think I may have used teams.get(i).getTeamName() wrong.    Sorry for being awkward, i'm bad at this.

Comment: @Dominic You need to select which team to use by changing 'i'.

Comment: @condorcraft110II Thanks, I've done it. I did it by doing 'i = info.position;'.